# How to see how far index of regex went on unsuccessful match

Tags: c#, .net, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex index in matching string where the match failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107382/regex-index-in-matching-string-where-the-match-failed)

If I have the subject:

```
0123456789abcdef...
```

and I have the pattern

```
\d+TEST
```

clearly it will fail. Now I would like to know the maximum index that was reached. In other words the regex engine would have done:

First it matches a digit so it moved its index to the next character which is also a digit. This steps will be repeated until the regex engine finds the number `9`. Because the next character is not a `T` it fails. **I will like to get the index `10` because the regex engine successfully moved 10 characters until it failed.** Is there a way of getting this info? I have to check the copy right of several documents and I do it with a regex. It will be nice if I could know on what index the regex failed.

Comment: If the question is general, for any pattern, there is no easy way of doing it, to my knowledge. For your specific case, you can simply match for `\d+` or `\d+(TEST)?`, but I guess that is too easy.

Comment: Thanks I will vote to delete this question then. Sorry

Comment: [This answer should give you a solution if you know what you are looking for.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11730035/637142

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two separate searches.

In your example code, the regex engine has in fact reached the end of the string - the engine itself considers every possible match when rejecting the string as having no matches.  You can't get the information "I moved to the 10th character and stopped" because the regex engine actually moved to the 16th character before it finished conclusively.

For what you're asking, you would first do this:

```
string source = @"0123456789abcdef";
Regex r = new Regex(@"\d+TEST")
MatchCollection matches = r.Matches(source); // Returns no matches
```

This would return whether or not a match for your full string exists.  If it fails, then execute this:

```
if (matches.Count == 0) {
    r = new Regex(@"\d+");
    MatchCollection matches = r.Matches(source);
    int maxpos = -1;
    foreach (Match m in matches) {
        if (m.Index + m.Length > maxpos) maxpos = m.Index + m.Length;
    }

    // returns 10
    return maxpos;
}
```

EDIT: One other alternative is to make the "TEST" string an optional match.  You can then review the list of matches, which will include both matches only on the digits and matches on the digits + TEST string.

```
string source = @"0123456789abcdef";
Regex r = new Regex(@"\d+(TEST)?")
MatchCollection matches = r.Matches(source); // Returns one match of 10 digits at position 0 - 10.
```

Comment: The regex is much longer than `\d+TEST` it is 10 lines long... If the regex skeepd from index 10 to the last then I will like to know that from c#

Comment: I added some code that I believe returns the value you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You could do this iteratively:

```
check for pattern \d+T
...then for patter \d+TE
....then for pattern \d+TES   and so on ...this way you can figure out how far you reached
```

Comment: @NikolaAnusev I would believe \d+ would match any # of digits. If you see the question specifies subject as: 123456789abcd.  Can you please elaborate the problem as you see it?