# decompile assembly into project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, decompiling, reflector

I will like to see the value of some private variables of the Regex class located on System.dll. If curious why I will like to twick that class look at [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726583/how-to-see-how-far-index-of-regex-went-on-unsuccessful-match)

So I will have to decompile `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.dll`

I am able to decompile that with reflector:

[image]

**Now my question is** Is there a way of creating a solution of visual studio with all those classes. There are hundreds of classes in there and I do not want to go one by one placing them to my new project.

Comment: Don't go there.  You can see private variable with the debugger.  You can even get them out of the object by using Reflection.

Comment: The problem is that the private variable `_index` get's set = 0 if the match fails. I will like to retrive it on the middle of the method. maybe I could do that from a different thread try to access it several times. that will be very unsafe lol

Comment: This seems like a very roundabout way to get the maximum position of a decimal value in a string if a match fails.  Surely there's a simpler way to look for it?  Are you searching through gigabytes of text?

Comment: Side note: decompiling assemblies with the goal to include resulting sources into your own project may have legal side effects. Check if you care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both ILSpy and JustDecompile allow exporting to a Visual Studio project.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to create the whole project look at http://www.reflector.net/ it has a addin called FileDisassembler http://www.reflector.net/add-ins/ that will do just what you are looking for.