# Using regex to identify a sequence of characters and build a string with it

Tags: c#, regex, stringbuilder

I have a tokenizer where tokens have a given interface:

```
interface IToken
{
    string Str { get; } //used after the token is built to get its content
    bool Success { get; } //has the informaition if the last 'TryAdd' was a success
    bool Valid { get; } //has the information if the current 'Str' is complete and Valid
    void TryAdd(char c); //Is called to add the next character to the token      
}
```

The general idea is that a list of implemented tokens are processed with each character of a given input in parallel.

The 'NumberToken' is too slow and i try to speed it up. I want to experiment with regex and i am wondering if the following is possible.

Given a pattern like `String patternINTFRACEXP = @"(\A)[0-9]+?\.[0-9]+?[eE]{1}[+-]{0,1}[0-9]+?(\Z)";` can i incrementally check if the expression could still be valid by adding one character at a time. I have written some Pseudocode to illustrate what i want that builder to do.

```
class PseudoCode : IToken
{
    String patternINTFRACEXP = @"(\A)[0-9]+?\.[0-9]+?[eE]{1}[+-]{0,1}[0-9]+?(\Z)";

    RegexBuilder builder;

    public PseudoCode()
    {
        builder = new RegexBuilder(patternINTFRACEXP);
        Success = true;
    }

    public string Str{ get { return builder.ToString(); } }

    public bool Success { get; private set; }

    public bool Valid { get { return builder.IsMatch(); } }

    public void TryAdd(char c) { Success &= builder.TryAdd(c); }
}
```

Does the combination of a StringBuilder and Regex already exist?

What would be an approach to implement `(builder as RegexBuilder).TryAdd(c as Char);` ?

Comment: Do you mean... given a regex and a target string, check whether the string *could be* the beginning of a string that will eventually match the regex?

Comment: @Rawling Yes. This is exactly what i meant. And i assume this has to be part of the Regex implementation at some level. I just dont know how to access/use that impleemntation.

Comment: Well, it's an interesting question, and I wish I knew the answer :D I guess if you could get inside the regex engine you would ask "did this fail at any point just because it reached the end of the input", but you don't have that kind of access in C#. You could modify the regular expression to allow `$` after every character, but that will require writing a regex parser yourself. I hope someone else can come up with an interesting solution.

Comment: Maybe i need to refactor a lot more. There is an interesting article on the web illustrating how tokenization using regex should be done: http://yourdotnetdesignteam.blogspot.de/2007/04/tokenize-string-with-c-regular.html#!/2007/04/tokenize-string-with-c-regular.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be oring the different steps of the pattern, starting with the longest like this

```
([0-9]+\.[0-9]+[eE]{1}[+-]{0,1}[0-9]+|[0-9]+?\.[0-9]+[eE]{1}[+-]{0,1}[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.[0-9]+[eE]{1}[+-]{0,1}|[0-9]+\.[0-9]+[eE]{1}|[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.|[0-9]+)
```

[DEMO HERE](http://regex101.com/r/wC0jD7/1)

I'm not familiar with c#, jsut answering on the regex part, the ungreedy operator is not needed as you have 'separators' (.,+,-,e) which split the string already.

I'll do an array with the different parts like this :

```
pattern = ["[0-9]+","\.","[0-9]+","[eE]{1}","[+-]{0,1}","[0-9]+"]
testpattern = ""
pattern.each do |p|
  testpattern += "#{testpatern}#{p}|#{testpattern}" 
end
testpattern.rstrip("|")
```

And test using testpatern. (stripping le leading | at end)

Its ruby code and not tested, so I may have a bug somewhere, but the idea is to build the pattern adding at each iteration the new part and ends up with the full ORed regex to test against.

Hope this will help

Alternative solution:
`^([0-9]+)[.]?([0-9]+|)(?:[eE]{1}([+-]{0,1}[0-9]+|)|)$`

[Updated DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wC0jD7/4)

It match exactly (if there's something not expected in the format it will not match) and capture the integer part, decimal part, and the exponent with the sign if there's one.

It will match for strings ending with e or E so could be your validation part.

Detailled explanation:

`^` <= start of line (instead of string)

`([0-9]+)` <= any number at least one time (1st capture)

`[.]?` <= a litteral dot 0 or 1 time (I prefer the [.] syntax at the escaped syntax for reading

`([0-9]+|)` <= the decimal part or nothing (second capture)

`(?:[eE]{1}([+-]{0,1}[0-9]+|)|)` <= many parts here, details:

`(?:` <= start of non capturing group

`[eE]{1}` <= 1 e upper or lowercase mandatory for the rest

`([+-]{0,1}[0-9]+|)` <= third capture group, the exponent signed or not or nothing (to match adding the E to your string)

`)` <= end of the not capturing group

`$` the end of line

Comment: Interesting, i maybe i will look into that. However i feel that the Regex implementation has to operate on a a stream of cahracters or something like that - i am looking for a solution along those lines.

Comment: I forgot to mention that with this solution you'll have to compare the match length and test length, I.e. 234z would be matched in 234 but the capture won't be the full string. Regex are supposed to work on a string not a stream in my opinion.

Comment: @Johannes to get further another question on SO which address this point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107382/regex-index-in-matching-string-where-the-match-failed

Comment: I think i will use this as a stepping stone to get into a state where i can completely refactor the tokenizer.