# "Tight" repeated key/value match

Tags: c#, regex

A string with a "tight" repeated pattern of key/value-pairs (for this example, key is "name" and value should be a single lower-case word)

```
string text = "name: abc name: def name: ghi name: jkl";
```

should be transformed to the output

> abc, def, ghi, jkl,

whereas any disturbance ("non-tight" so to say) in the pattern like in

```
string text = "name: abc x name: def name: ghi name: jkl";
```

should cause the match to fail, something along the lines of

> abc, ## Exception occurred: x cannot be matched to the pattern ##

I have tried

```
string text = "name: abc name: def name: ghi name: jkl";
string pattern = @"name:\s*([a-z])*\s*";

MatchCollection ms = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);

foreach (Match m in ms)
{
    Console.Write(m.Groups[1].Value+", ");
}
```

but it returns

> c, f, i, l,

What is causing this odd behavior and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike most other regex flavours, C# (.Net)'s engine actually keeps track of repeated captures through the [`Captures`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `Group` class.

> ## Group.Captures Property
>
> Gets a collection of all the captures matched by the capturing group, in innermost-leftmost-first order (or innermost-rightmost-first order if the regular expression is modified with the [RegexOptions.RightToLeft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) option).

What this means is that by accessing `Groups[1]` (as shown in the code below) and then accessing the `Captures` property, we're effectually getting the value of each repeated capture on our string.

---

#### Code

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##hVFNT8MwDD23v8KqOLT7iMR11QTSNKEhdgEEh2lIIXO3QJqWOB0F1N9e0rSTEByQEst@efazHUFTURhs24qk3sPdB1nM0/BnxG6kfvsF3WNt2S3uK8XNsi4NEslCUxqGQnEiWNY8LxXCVxgGZLmVAo6F3MGaSx0nDg4cbFzBzRZ6h2AOGt/hBHeUINI8xxnwZwG9t8Ns8PYHOXgvryqa/GLX//AdvUmdcSNgDcbbXt8j8WX0FF/Mev4o3vDp53acwCgZn0VJl5e5nXFxiPtugUDq0xz9dIHMYl@WrWjNbUdNhpfAx5B7O@/F2YmTesbC7bJQyB6NtOjWj4MQuy7c/qIJuJOZIocFL21lEETXgK/IrkxRlbQ537LhkYBQobAg2ANXFSa9SAOoCIeW/gpGK33kyn2Z1GVloyEn9LcJm7b9Bg)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Example {

    static void Main() {
        string[] strings = new string[]{
            "name: abc name: def name: ghi name: jkl",
            "name: abc x name: def name: ghi name: jkl"
        };
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?:name: *([a-z]+) *)+$");
        foreach(string s in strings) {
            if(regex.IsMatch(s)) {
                Match match = regex.Match(s);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", from Capture c in match.Groups[1].Captures select c.Value));
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Results

```
name: abc name: def name: ghi name: jkl     # abc, def, ghi, jkl
name: abc x name: def name: ghi name: jkl   # Invalid input
```

Comment: This is it! I already had the suspicion that it has something to do with the captures, but I had no clue how to use it. Do you happen to know how I could detect at which index in the string the match failed first (ie. the "x")?

Comment: @oliver unfortunately, the `Regex` class doesn't contain such a property. The only way to accomplish this using the `Regex` class is to either run a second regex on it (such as `^(?:name: *[a-z]+ *)+`) to get the location it failed. Otherwise, you can actually edit the source to do what you want as discussed in this answer from [Regex index in matching string where the match failed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/107540/3600709)

Answer (score 4):

You just need to move the `*` inside the parentheses in order to capture the full string. If you want to guard against invalid input, then a regular expression is not strictly necessary. This assumes that your values cannot have spaces, becuase that would be a much more difficult problem to solve.

```
void Main()
{
    string validText = "name: abc name: def name: ghi name: jkl";
    string invalidText = "name: abc x name: def name: ghi name: jkl";
    string validPattern = @"name:\s*([a-z]*)\s*";

    if (!Validate(invalidText))
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("invalid input");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Input '{invalidText}' produces: {exception.Message}");
        }
    }

    MatchCollection ms = Regex.Matches(validText, validPattern);

    Console.Write($"Input '{validText}' produces: ");
    foreach (Match m in ms)
    {
        Console.Write(m.Groups[1].Value + ", ");
    }
}

public static bool Validate(string input)
{
    var pairs = input.Split(' ');
    return !pairs.Where((item, index) => index % 2 != 0).Any(item => item.EndsWith(":"));
}

// Input 'name: abc x name: def name: ghi name: jkl' produces: invalid input
// Input 'name: abc name: def name: ghi name: jkl' produces: abc, def, ghi, jkl,
```

https://regex101.com/r/qsQNr1/1

Comment: This only answers half the question.

Comment: Jeez, I am so stupid. Originally I had it right, but then I played with the parentheses... And what about detecting the disturbing "x"?

Comment: Updated in an attempt to answer the other half of the question.

Comment: @DanWilson: Hmmm, this just covers a very specific deviation from the pattern. But I want to catch ANY deviation from the pattern sequence.

Comment: Updated based on previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use

```
var result = "name: abc name: def name: ghi name: jkl".Split(new [] { "name: " }, StringSplitOptions.None).Where(a=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(a)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Of course I could, but I don't want to because the code tends to get ugly and convoluted with Split. Matching patterns with RegEx is a lot cleaner and after all this is what it is for.

Comment: @oliver it is not recommended to overuse Regex, 
just keep your code simple. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Comment: Okay, whoever recommended this didn't take into account that I love Regex ;-)

Comment: I do as well, just take in count other developer who are not fond of Regex that will need to read your code :P

Comment: Besides this, if I change the pattern to something more complicated, then I have to rewrite the whole split expression or replace it with something completely different. That's an objective pro for regex in my opinion.

Comment: "...not fond of...": Yeah that's true, but in this case I have full control. This is a private project.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally also found a solution for getting the "error position", ie. the position where the repeated match fails first. I hope that anyone who has the same problem stumbles upon this straying answer:

```
string s = "name: abc x name: def name: ghi name: jkl";
string pattern = @"\Gname:\s*([a-z]+)\s*";

int endOfLastMatch = 0;

// by using the \G anchor we can manage pattern repetition in a for-loop
for (Match m = Regex.Match(s, pattern); m.Success; m = m.NextMatch())
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value+ ", ");

    // keep track of until where matches were successful
    endOfLastMatch = m.Index + m.Length;
}

// in case that the match has failed, report where it has happened
if (endOfLastMatch != s.Length) 
{
    int reportSize = Math.Min(s.Length-endOfLastMatch, 10);
    string remainder = s.Substring(endOfLastMatch, reportSize);
    Console.WriteLine("Error: RegEx match failed at index "
        +endOfLastMatch+" (\""+remainder+"...\")");
}
```

Output:

> abc,
>
> Error: RegEx match failed at index 10 ("x name: de...")

The magic happens in the `\G` anchor, which allows us to use `NextMatch` for pattern repetition, while at the same time enforcing that the next match follows directly adjacent to the last match. It is the match-boundary equivalent to the `^` (line or string start) anchor, so to say.

The price is that we don't parse the text in one chunk (like in the accepted answer) but rather in a for loop. But since it is comparatively small, I think this is more than acceptable.